# GeoDjango mapping points on a map

Tags: javascript, django, kml, geodjango

I'm pretty new to this stuff. I have a problem where, it shows up fine on the admin map, but the points don't actually show up on the public map. I have objects created in the database, so I don't think it might be from either javascript or KML.

Thanks,

David

models.py

```
1 from django.contrib.gis.db import models
2 #from apps.pages.models import DataEntry
3 
4 class PointLayer( models.Model ):
5     geometry = models.PointField( blank=True,null=True )
6     objects  = models.GeoManager()
7 
8     site = models.CharField( max_length=50, blank=True )
9     snow_Depth = models.FloatField( )
10     albedo = models.FloatField()
11     snow_Density = models.FloatField()
12     lon = models.FloatField()
13     lat = models.FloatField()
14 
15     def __unicode__( self ):
16         return self.site
17 
18     def description( self ):
19         ret = "<b>Site:</b>" + self.site + "<br/>"
20         ret += "<b>Snow Depth:</b>" + str(self.snow_Depth) + "<br/>"
21         ret += "<b>Albedo:</b>" + str(self.albedo) + "<br/>"
22         ret += "<b>Snow Density:</b>" + str(self.snow_Density) + "<br/>"
23         ret += "<a href='/map/" + str(self.pk) + "/'>Full Point Record</a><br/>"
24         ret += "<hr/>"
25         return ret;
```

map.js

```
1 var map, layer;
2 var lon = 0;
3 var lat = 0;
4 var zoom = 2;
5 var currentKmlObjects = {};
6 
7 function init(){
8 
9     map = new OpenLayers.Map('map');
10 
11         map.addControl( new    OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher({'div':OpenLayers.Util.getElement('layerswitcher')}));
12 
13     var gphy = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google("Google Physical",
14                                             {type: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN});
15 
16     var gmap = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google("Google Streets",
17                                             {numZoomLevels: 20});
18 
19     var ghyb = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google("Google Hybrid",
20                                             {type: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID,
21                                              numZoomLevels: 20});
22 
23     var gsat = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google("Google Satellite",
24                                             {type: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,
25                                              numZoomLevels: 22});
26 
27     var points = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Albedo Data Points", {
28         strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
29         protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
30             url: "http://albedo.csrcdev.com/map/test.kml",
31             format: new OpenLayers.Format.KML({
32                 extractStyles: true,
33                 extractAttributes: true
34             })
35         })
36     });
37 
38     map.addLayers([gsat, gphy, gmap, ghyb, points]);
39 
40     //Google.v3 uses ESPG:900913 as projection, so we have to 
41     //transform our coordinates
42     map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(lon, lat).transform(
43         new OpenLayers.Projection("ESPG:4326"),
44         map.getProjectionObject()
45     ), zoom);
46 
47     //Interaction not needed for initial display.
48     selectControl = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(points);
49     map.addControl(selectControl);
50     selectControl.activate();
51     points.events.on({
52         'featureselected': onFeatureSelect,
53         'featureunselected': onFeatureUnselect
54     });
55 }
56 
57 //Interactive functions:
58 function onPopupClose( evt ){
59     //this is the pop-up
60     var feature = this.feature;
61     if( feature.layer ){
62         selectControl.unselect( feature );
63     }
64     //After 'move-end' or 'refresh' events on POIs layer all
65     //features have been destroyed by the Strategy.BBOX
66     else{
67         this.destroy();
68     }
69 }
70 
71 function onFeatureSelect( evt ){
72     feature = evt.feature;
73     popup = new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud( "featurePopup",
74                             feature.geometry.getBounds().getCenterLonLat(),
75                             new OpenLayers.Size( 100,100 ),
76                             "<h2>" + feature.attributes.name + "</h2>" +
77                             feature.attributes.description,
78                             null, true, onPopupClose );
79     feature.popup = popup;
80     popup.feature = feature;
81     map.addPopup( popup, true );
82 }
83 
84 function onFeatureUnselect( evt ){
85     feature = evt.feature;
86     if( feature.popup ){
87         popup.feature = null;
88         map.removePopup( feature.popup );
89         feature.popup.destroy();
90         feature.popup = null;
91     }
92 }
93 
94 
95
```

main.kml

```
1 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
2 <kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
3 <Document>
4     <name><![CDATA[{%if doc_name%}{{doc_name}}{%else%}HMAP{%endif%}]]></name>
5     <open>1</open>
6     <snippet maxLines="2"></snippet>
7     <description><![CDATA[Exported from {% if doc_name %}{{ doc_name }}{% else %}HMAP{% endif %}]]></description>
8     {% block styles %}
9     {% if styles %}
10     {% for style in styles %}
11     <Style id="{{style.name}}">
12         <LineStyle>
13             <color>{{style.color}}</color>
14             <width>0.2</width>
15         </LineStyle>
16         <PolyStyle>
17             <outline>1</outline>
18             <fill>{% if style.fill %}{{ style.fill }}{% else %}1{% endif %}</fill>
19             <color>{{style.color}}</color>
20         </PolyStyle>
21         <IconStyle>
22             <color>BFFFFFFF</color>
23             <scale>{% if style.icon_scale %}{{ style.icon_scale }}{% else %}0.6{% endif %}</scale>
24             <Icon>
25                 <href>{% if style.icon %}{{style.icon}}{% else %}http:://albedo.csrcdev.com/media/images/icons/marker.png{% endif %}</href>
26                 </Icon>
27                 <hotSpot x="0.5" y="0.5" xunits="fraction" yunits="fraction"/>
28         </IconStyle>
29         <LabelStyle>
30             <color>00000000</color>
31         </LabelStyle>
32     </Style>
33     {% endfor %}
34     {% else %}
35     <Style id="default">
36         <LineStyle>
37             <color>8800ff00</color>
38             <width>0.2</width>
39         </LineStyle>
40         <PolyStyle>
41             <outline>1</outline>
42             <fill>1</fill>
43             <color>8800ff00</color>
44         </PolyStyle>
45         <IconStyle>
46             <color>BFFFFFFF</color>
47             <scale>{% if style.icon %}{{style.icon_scale}}{% else %}0.6{% endif %}</scale>
48             <Icon>
49                 <href>{% if style.icon %}{{style.icon}}{% else %}http://albedo.csrcdev.com/media/images/icons/marker.png{% endif %}</href>
50             </Icon>
51             <hotSpot x="0.5" y="0.5" xunits="fraction" yunits="fraction"/>
52         </IconStyle>
53         <LabelStyle>
54             <color>00000000</color>
55         </LabelStyle>
56         </Style>
57         {% endif %}
58         {% endblock %}
59         {% block features %}
60     <Folder>
61         <name>Features</name>
62         {% for geometry in geometries %}
63         <Placemark id="{{geometry.pk}}">
64             <name><![CDATA[{{geometry.name}}]]></name>
65             <description><![CDATA[{%block description%}{{geometry.description|safe}}{% endblock%}]]></description>
66             <Snippet maxLines="2"></Snippet>
67             {% if geometry.style %}
68             <styleUrl>#{{geometry.style}}</styleUrl>
69             {% else %}
70             <styleUrl>#defualt</styleUrl>
71             {% endif %}
72             {% if geometry.timespane %}
73             <TimeSpan>
74                 {% if geometry.timespan.begin %}<begin>{{geometry.timespan.begin}}</begin>{% endif %}
75                 {% if geometry.timespan.begin %}<end>{{geometry.timespan.end}}</end>{% endif %}
76                 {{geometry.geometry.kml|safe}}
77             </TimeSpan>
78             {% endif %}
79             {% block extend_data %}{% endblock %}
80             {{ geometry.geometry.kml|safe }}
81         </Placemark>
82         {% endfor %}
83     </Folder>
84         {% endblock %}
85     <Folder>
86         <name>Information Points</name>
87         <open>0</open>
88         {% block placemarks %}{{ placemarks }}{% endblock %}
89     </Folder>
90 </Document>
91 </kml>
92
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first test your KML by going to http://maps.google.com/?q=http://your.site/your.kml

If that works as expected, then you know it's your javascript -- I would suggest providing a link to your site which will make it much easier for someone to debug.

Comment: It was Javascript - I'm pretty new to this, thanks for your help.